# Is there a way to ignore to register a nib or a class for TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My table simply has row with a `UIImageView`. When I assign the image directly like the below mentioned way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *identifier = @"cellidentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.imageView.image = [self.backgroundImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

It returns error:

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellidentifier - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'.

So I wonder is there a way to ignore to register a nib or a class for `UITableViewCell` in order to shorten the code in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom class for your cell then you should register the class (in viewDidLoad),use `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` if the cell is made in a xib file.

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

else write `cellForRowAtIndexPath` tableView delegate as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //Configure cell
   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one line in your viewDidLoad to resolve the error

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Songcell"; // copy this identifier and paste it into your storyboard tableviewcell indetifier 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UIImageView *IMAGEVIEWNAME = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:YOUR_TAG]; // give tag to your imageview from storyboard and access it here 

    IMAGEVIEWNAME.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGENAME"];
    return cell;
}
```

Give same name in your storyboard tableviewcell identifier

**cellidentifier** with this name . i just give my cell identifier songcell.

[image: I just give it here songcell at that part you give it **cellidentifier**]

Answer (score 0):

Put your cell identifier in storyboard as below screenshot.

[image]